# Unable to connect remote server by using Myrtille

Tags: remote-server, remote-desktop, rdp

I installed the Myrtille (Remote Desktop application). And I can see the connection page but it's not connecting to the remote server using valid credentials. Is there any brief documentation available for setting up the connection. Or is there any alternative for this in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md#troubleshoot

In my case widows defender quarantine this file :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Myrtille\bin\wfreerdp.exe

But at the project siad that it is false positives:
https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/6336

Once I restored file- it started to work...